# recent prices changes

Tags: exchange-rate, marketplace

Over the past three weeks the prices of bitcoins in U.S. dollars has more than doubled.  Does anyone know why?  Is there some recent publicity that drove up interest (so that maybe prices will fall after it dies down)?

Comment: You generally shouldn't ask questions that require the answer to be a speculation ("so that maybe prices will fall after it dies down?") on StackExchange. As it's not really the main part of the question, I won't vote to close it, but please edit it out and try to avoid those in the future.

Comment: At the very least this question should be rewritten so that the time span referred to is included in the question. This is especially important for the title so that people looking for answers about the rise in late 2011, early 2012 can easily find it. "Recent price changes" will be a meaningless title in just a few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

According to Google Trends, there was an article on Slashdot about Bitcoins:

http://www.google.com/trends?q=bitcoin&ctab=0&geo=all&date=mtd&sort=0

And one could also attribute it to some other little things, like the small hype about The Good Wife's upcoming episode, or many prominent websites accepting Bitcoin donations:

http://www.thebitcointrader.com/2011/12/bitcoin-bounty-ladder.html

But then again, pricing Bitcoins at 2$ might've been psychologically too low for some people (like the miners that heavily invested in hardware around the big bubble).

All in all, there isn't any sure prediction about how the Bitcoin price will behave, as the project is still young. Anyone can speculate, and your guess is as good as mine. If you want to discuss this issue, the question should be addressed on the forum, not on StackExchange.

Comment: Another thing is the upcoming CES where the bit-pay people will be operating a Bitcoin booth.